# Github pages renders blank react app that works fine on local

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

[Link to repo](https://github.com/aermkv/portfolio2023)

This is working fine on local and was working fine at https://aermkv.github.io/portfolio2023/ before I tried adding a custom domain through GitHub pages. I have since removed it, but I am still getting a blank page with the Mixed Content errors (see below).

[image]

What changed when I tried to add and then removed the custom domain and I how do I get it back to working condition? My understanding was that even once linked with the custom domain (I'm trying to have my current squarespace domain load this project), the [username].github.io/[project] would still work fine.

Thanks

Comment: As it clearly says, you're trying to load an http resource inside an https web page. Make sure your custom domain supports https and call assets through https URL.

Comment: So where did that change come from since it was working fine before attempting to link the custom domain, and how would I reverse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The github.io site is loading fine for me.. Unless you already fixed it my suspect would be your browser cache. Trying clearing cache and cookies before running it again.

[Working Repro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4Uzw.png)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's all it was, thanks!